# Can I access a blob URL in an external page?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that creates an object URL from a blob of data: `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

It returns a URL such as: `blob:chrome-extension://igilfmkkaffffeeigpidagfgmalaofcb/8b81c1e1-1492-4c36-bec8-537e816abf88`.

I want to access this blob of data in an external website (not a chrome extension). Is this possible or do I have to use the file system API? When I currently try to do it I get a `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

My manifest has this key: `"web_accessible_resources": ["*"]`

Website A content script -> Background Page create blob -> Website B use blob

Relevant: [Pass large blob or file from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847708/pass-large-blob-or-file-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: So which part of the answer in the linked question did you not get?

Comment: The website that the content script is running on and the website that I want to access the file from are two different domains.

Comment: It's all covered in that answer. You need either another content script to "convert" the blob, or use `data:` URIs. I could dupehammer it as a duplicate but I'll leave that decision to RobW (author of the answer in question and also a gold badge) when he comes around.